# "ИCTИHA" returned by EXACT Function in Open Office Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

=EXACT(A2;A3)returns ИCTИHA

ИCTИHA is true in Russian apparently . . .

Anyone else seeing this?

Apache Open Office 4.13
AOO413m1(Build:9783)  -  Rev. 1761381
2016-09-29 02:39:19

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your Locale has been set to Russian.  Go to *Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Languages* and change Locale setting.